# Facebook Audio Player Broken?

Tags: facebook, feed, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I am having a problem with sharing/liking links with Open Graph Protocol data for audio/mp3 files.  They look OK on Facebook news feed/timeline, but when you click play button, it won't play.  It says: `undefined` (see screenshot).

[image]

So I tried playing some older posts of links with OG meta data about audio/mp3 files, and they don't play either.

**EDIT**

I did some firebug inspection and the audio player is Flash based.  I think the problem is in the flashvars part of the embed code.  There is a flashvar for `src` but its value appears to be a SHA256 checksum instead of the URL of the mp3 file.

Comment: posted a bug report, too: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165246693563413

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like Facebook have finally fixed it - at least, the audio players on my page have started working again.  Hopefully that means you should see it fixed relatively soon, depending on how this is rolled out.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and I do not really understand what is the cause of this!!

I have tried the meta tags setting as provided here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

Give them a try also(if you have not yet) and see if they work for you.

Comment: That URL got my hopes up, but the end result on Facebook Timeline/wall is unchanged and audio player still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has apparently removed the player.  Their help file suggests making a music video.  Very irritating.

Comment: Can you provide a link to Facebook help page that says this?

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a current bug: 
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165246693563413